# Filter Data by Checkbox Selections: Single Column + Multiple Columns (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, filter, filtering, spreadsheet, checkboxlist

I am trying to figure out how to allow folks to filter a data set by clicking on checkboxes of their choice. [Here is a sample spreadsheet to will better help explain my objectives.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1goUZX_9UZQd6MUQIGrNzcSbADU6JplDZeVNw2lktPVU/edit?usp=sharing) I have two separate tabs: one to filter using only one column of checkboxes, and another that looks to filter data using multiple columns of checkboxes.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
=filter(A5:B,xmatch(year(A5:A),filter(E5:E,D5:D)),xmatch(B5:B,filter(H5:H,G5:G)))
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thank you! What if I am looking at add a regexmatch into the formula? I have added a new tab to help explain.

Comment: it doesnt need a regexmatch; jus an extra condition like `C5:C=I1`